# How to create external procedures in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

How do I create functions / procedures in Vertica that make use of SQL with clauses such as  `FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT` etc ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information is generally found in the documentation.

Comment: Their support and documentation are [quite vague about this](https://community.vertica.com/vertica/topics/since_stored_procedure_is_not_supported_by_vertica_so_whats_the_alternative_to_handle_it) and make no mention of vsql. The docs point to using `c++` or shell scripts, but this work around can use plain sql after all. Why would you downvote this :/ ? It took me an hour to figure this out and this information can save someone that time.

Answer (score 10):

Vertica's `create function` syntax prohibits the use of certain clauses in the `expression`.

### Create function

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
... [[db-name.]schema.]function-name ( [ argname argtype  [, ...] ] )
... RETURN rettype
... AS 
... BEGIN
...... RETURN expression;
... END;
```

> Note: Only one RETURN expression is allowed in the CREATE FUNCTION
>   definition. FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT, aggregation,
>   analytics and meta function are **not allowed**.

To get around that you can use a procedure instead. Procedures in Vertica are not comparable to stored-procedures / PL-SQL (Vertica does not support them). They are installed scripts written in another language (such as Bash). They take the syntax...

### Create Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [[db-name.]schema.]procedure-name ( 
... [ argname ] [ argtype [,...] ] )
... AS 'exec-name'
... LANGUAGE 'language-name'
... USER 'OS-user'
```

You can configure a procedure to call a vsql client using bash. The following script does that. Your script can also take parameters passed by Vertica.

### Bash procedure script

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql --command 'select count(*) from my_table where condition > value;' -w 'XXX' --echo-all -h host db_name user_name
exit 0
```

Install the script using the admintool GUI or the command line

### Install external script

The script must have the right owner and the `setuid` flag must be set. You can do that using [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

```
$ admintools -t install_procedure -d vmartdb -f /scratch/helloworld.sh -p ownerpassword
Installing external procedure...
External procedure installed
```

### Create the script in the database and then call it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_name() AS 'my_script.sh' LANGUAGE 'external' USER 'db_user';
select my_proc_name();
```

Comment: why the negative point for him ! the guy put some effot into this answer ! come on guys !!!

Comment: @Up_One Because external procedures do not return result of execution: _The external procedure cannot communicate back to HP Vertica._ ;)

Answer (score -2):

Vertica does not support Stored Procedures as you have in some DBs.  Instead it has User Defined Functions.  You write them in Java or whatever but it runs INSIDE the database as if it were an SP.  (it also supported External Procedures to run stuff outside the DB if you what you want)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. In particular, you should provide an example of `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `LIMIT` in a Stored Procedure; otherwise, you haven't really answered the question as asked.