# Create anonymous Block with Exception Handling in Vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have an issue with Vertica alter column size

I have some columns I want to resize
with this command

```
alter table TABLE_NAME  alter column  COLUMN_NAME   SET DATA TYPE     varchar(100);
```

But when executing via some of my Vertica DB I get this error:

```
SQL Error [2629] [42701]: [Vertica][VJDBC](2629) ROLLBACK: Column "COLUMN_NAME" is already of type "varchar(100)"
  [Vertica][VJDBC](2629) ROLLBACK: Column "COLUMN_NAME" is already of type "varchar(100)"
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](2629) ROLLBACK: Column "COLUMN_NAME" is already of type "varchar(100)"
```

But some of my columns already is this size - I have multiple Vertica database some of them, not the same size.
I have a huge amount of column I want to resize and align to specific size
I don't want to create different SQL's file for each DB.

At my previous experience with **ORACLE DB**, I would solve Exception Handling with anonymous Blocks easy  as that:

```
BEGIN
  .. code statements go here ..
EXCEPTION
  .. exception handlers go here ..
END;
```

I was thinking of Creating a Function/Produce at Vetica but is just a huge overkill - since Vertica doesn't support Simple Function writing like **PLSQL**

Creating a function in Vertica is not possible since it's not supporting **SQL** commands execution - or select queries
as i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432232/how-to-create-external-procedures-in-vertica)

How can I create a simple Block to handle and ignore this exception ?

Comment: Can't you identify the columns requiring a resizing before ? For example, by querying the table "columns" with a query like :
select * from columns where data_type like 'varchar%' and data_type_length <> 100;

Comment: No its a long story,  I don't want to query system table for the current size.
I want to have one SQL file to be executed via all the existing Different Vertica DB I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can **easily** build the script you're looking for using a *"SQL generating SQL"* approach:

```
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name ||
    ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_name || ' SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);'
FROM 
    v_catalog.columns 
WHERE 
    data_type !='varchar(100)'
;
```

It will generate in output something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE tpch.partsupp ALTER COLUMN ps_partkey SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
 ALTER TABLE tpch.partsupp ALTER COLUMN ps_suppkey SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
 ALTER TABLE tpch.partsupp ALTER COLUMN ps_availqty SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
 ALTER TABLE tpch.partsupp ALTER COLUMN ps_supplycost SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
 ALTER TABLE tpch.partsupp ALTER COLUMN ps_comment SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
 ALTER TABLE tpch.customer ALTER COLUMN c_custkey SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);
```

And, of course you can add all sort of filters and/or change the generated SQL...

**EDIT**

It looks like OP - for some reason - don't want to create a script. Then just use *pipes*...

```
$ vsql -f - <<-EOF | vsql -f -
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name ||
    ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_name || ' SET DATA TYPE varchar(100);'
FROM 
    v_catalog.columns 
WHERE 
    data_type !='varchar(100)'
EOF
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid sepperated script

Comment: Then just pipe the output of the script here above to `vsql` reading from STDIN and you will avoid a separated script. Easy.